# How to use JSON appender in Logback?

Tags: logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I am trying to output all my log events in JSON format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <!--<appender-ref ref="kafkaAppender" />-->
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Maven Dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I see an error while running this configuration. Did i miss anything?

here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder.headerBytes()[B
at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.encoderInit(OutputStreamAppender.java:180)
at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.setOutputStream(OutputStreamAppender.java:171)
at ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender.start(ConsoleAppender.java:81)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had encountered the same error while using 4.7 version of the logstash-logback-encoder, and upgrading to 4.11 resolved the issue.

Ref- https://github.com/thumbtack/becquerel/issues/2